# Decode the object array

Tags: php, arrays, decode

(sorry for my bad english, hope you understand)
Is there any way to decode this array ?
http://status.mc-host.cz/s8.mc-host.cz:25637-feed

With Json_decode it not worked :/

I need take this content for example:

```
If ($data['status'] == "online") {
   //something
} Else {
   //offline
}
```

Thank for help

Comment: That is the result of a PHP print_r(). json_decode decodes JSON. That is not JSON.

Comment: Are you printing this array from your application, or are you trying to retrieve this array from the web and use it in your application?

Comment: decode what? than link gives you an array. You only have to traverse the array with a for or a foreach.

Answer (score 1):

This is the output of a print_r statement. The simplest way to check to see if your condition going to be like this.

```
    $online = false;
    $data = file("http://status.mc-host.cz/s8.mc-host.cz:25637-feed", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    foreach($data as $line){
         if (strpos($line, "[Status] => online") !== false){
             $online = true;
         }
    }
    if($online){
       // do something
    } else {
       // offline
    }
```

It's worth noting that this solution does not decode the array, it just checks to see if your condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but this might work:

```
function print_r_reverse($in) { 
    $lines = explode("\n", trim($in)); 
    if (trim($lines[0]) != 'Array') { 
        // bottomed out to something that isn't an array 
        return $in; 
    } else { 
        // this is an array, lets parse it 
        if (preg_match("/(\s{5,})\(/", $lines[1], $match)) { 
            // this is a tested array/recursive call to this function 
            // take a set of spaces off the beginning 
            $spaces = $match[1]; 
            $spaces_length = strlen($spaces); 
            $lines_total = count($lines); 
            for ($i = 0; $i < $lines_total; $i++) { 
                if (substr($lines[$i], 0, $spaces_length) == $spaces) { 
                    $lines[$i] = substr($lines[$i], $spaces_length); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        array_shift($lines); // Array 
        array_shift($lines); // ( 
        array_pop($lines); // ) 
        $in = implode("\n", $lines); 
        // make sure we only match stuff with 4 preceding spaces (stuff for this array and not a nested one) 
        preg_match_all("/^\s{4}\[(.+?)\] \=\> /m", $in, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER); 
        $pos = array(); 
        $previous_key = ''; 
        $in_length = strlen($in); 
        // store the following in $pos: 
        // array with key = key of the parsed array's item 
        // value = array(start position in $in, $end position in $in) 
        foreach ($matches as $match) { 
            $key = $match[1][0]; 
            $start = $match[0][1] + strlen($match[0][0]); 
            $pos[$key] = array($start, $in_length); 
            if ($previous_key != '') $pos[$previous_key][1] = $match[0][1] - 1; 
            $previous_key = $key; 
        } 
        $ret = array(); 
        foreach ($pos as $key => $where) { 
            // recursively see if the parsed out value is an array too 
            $ret[$key] = print_r_reverse(substr($in, $where[0], $where[1] - $where[0])); 
        } 
        return $ret; 
    } 
}
```

From PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#93529